# values in a array ant that array is in another array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I find the values in a array ant that array is in another array?
So, I'll assign my variables with correct values!

Here is my json file :

```
    {
    "id": "number12345",
    "model": "324",
    "discount": [],
    "note": [],
    "quantity": "2",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "first": [
        {
           "type": "billing",
           "name": "Jo",
           "number": "01"
        },
        {
           "type": "shipping",
           "name": "Susuan",
           "number": "03"
        }
     ]
    },
  {
     "seconde": [
        {
           "type": "billing",
           "name": "Jony",
           "number": "02"
        },
        {
           "type": "shipping",
           "name": "Ladye",
           "number": "05"
        }
         ]
       }
    ]
    }
```

here are my variables with the values I want to get:

```
$firstTypeOne = 'billing';
$firstTypeTwo = 'shipping';

$firstNameOne = 'Jo';
$firstNameTwo = 'Susuan';

$firstNumberOne = '01';
$firstNumberTwo = '03';
```

I tried this for find the values :

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    ini_set('log_errors', 1);

    $dataJson = "mydatafile.json";

    $dataJson = file_get_contents($dataJson);

    //var_dump(json_decode($dataJson));
    //echo '<BR>';
    //var_dump(json_decode($dataJson, true));

    $decodeDataJson = json_decode($dataJson);

    foreach ($decodeDataJson->addresses->first as $obj) //here is line 17 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
        {

            echo $firstTypeOne = $obj->type . '< br>' . $firstNameOne = $obj->name . '< br>' . $firstNameTwo = $obj->name;
        }
```

And I have some error :   here is the error message:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php on line 17

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php.php on line 17

Why have not I my "echo"?
How can I assign the correct values to my variables?

have a nice day
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is nested multiple levels deep. You need two loops to access the variables you are seeking. Plus, since the inner elements are named differently you need a way to grab that property. Try this:

```
foreach ($json->addresses as $obj) {
        foreach($obj->{key(get_object_vars($obj))} as $innerObject) {

            echo $firstTypeOne = $innerObject->type . '< br>' . $firstNameOne = $innerObject->name . '< br>' . $firstNameTwo = $innerObject->name;
        }
}
```

I hope that helps! Also consider using an online json viewer so you could easily see exactly how to access the property you are seeking. That's what I just did. :)

Comment: Hi Chip, `  foreach ($decodeDataJson->addresses as $obj) {
   foreach($obj->first as $innerObject) {     // line 32
    
    $firstTypeOne = $innerObject->type;   // billing
    $firstNameOne = $innerObject->name;   // Jo
    $firstNameTwo = $innerObject->name;   //Susuan
   }
}


echo  $firstTypeOne . "<br>" . $firstNameOne . "<br>" . $firstNameTwo;` but I get bad values with alerts:

_Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$first in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php on line 32

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 32_

**shipping
Susuan
Susuan**

Answer (score -1):

@Chip Dean

I think this is not necessary. Because you need just to know the structure and get them directly. So if he want to get the elements of an object or array in his json, he can use this directly if it is not empty!

As I wrote, he should try to var_dump

```
$decodeDataJson
$decodeDataJson->addresses
$decodeDataJson->addresses->first
```

And before he got his loop, he should add

```
if(isset($variable))
{ 
foreach() ...
```

With isset he can handle his exception.

Comment: It is necessary if he wants to print the values of both people. Also, addresses is an array. You cannot do $decodeDataJson->addresses->first. You must do $decodeDataJson->addresses[0]->first

Comment: and I also tried this one : `foreach ($donnee_decode_json->addresses[0]->first  as $obj) 
 {
    $firstTypeOne = $obj->type;   // billing
    $firstNameOne = $obj->name;   // Jo
    $firstNameTwo = $obj->name;   //Susuan
 }



echo  $firstTypeOne . '<br>' . $firstNameOne . '<br>' . $firstNameTwo;` but It doesn't work